# Large amount of words unable to fit into table (using multirow, multicol)

Tags: tables

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % for a ever so slightly more open "look"
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{c X|c |c |c |c|c |}
    \cline{3-7}
     & & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{fference} & \multirow{2}{*}{t} & \multirow{2}{*}{df} & \multirow{2}{*}{Sig.(2-tailed)} \\
    \cline{3-4}
     & & Lower & Upper &  & &  \\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|c}{Pair 1} & Apple E(AM) & & 33.93\%, 54.47\% & 9.734 & 9 & .000 \\
    \hline
      \end{tabularx}
\caption{too large words}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Outcome:
[image]

If I change to:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % for a ever so slightly more open "look"
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{c X|c |c |c |c|c |}
    \cline{3-7}
     & & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Testing One Testing One Testing One Testing One} & \multirow{2}{*}{t} & \multirow{2}{*}{df} & \multirow{2}{*}{Sig.(2-tailed)} \\
    \cline{3-4}
     & & Lower & Upper &  & &  \\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|c}{Pair 1} & Apple Banana Bal Bal Bal Bal(AM) & & 33.93\%, 54.47\% & 9.734 & 9 & .000 \\
    \hline
      \end{tabularx}
\caption{too large words}
\end{table}
```

\end{document}

Outcome:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, something like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{}
\usepackage{makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % for a ever so slightly more open "look"
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{c X|c |c |c |c |c |}
    \cline{3-7}
     & & \multicolumn{2}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{8em}|}{Testing One Testing One Testing One Testing One} & \multirow{5}{*}{t} & \multirow{5}{*}{df} & \multirow{5}{*}{\makecell{Sig.\\(2-tailed)}} \\
    \cline{3-4}
     & & Lower & Upper &  & &  \\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|c}{Pair 1} & Apple Banana Bal Bal Bal Bal(AM) & 33.93\%, &  54.47\% & 9.734 & 9 & .000 \\
    \hline
      \end{tabularx}
\caption{too large words}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, very good. What is the meaning of `>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{8em}|`?

Comment: @user193541: A `p` type column is usually justified. With `>{\centering\arraybackslash}` you can instead horizontally center the contents of a `p` type column.

Comment: @user193541, that contents in `p` (paragraph) column is centered. I strongly encourage you to read some introductory text about table writing. For example https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables.

Comment: I was thinking `\multicolumn{num_cols}{alignment}{contents}` which is for `alignment`

Comment: @user193541: Actually, the second argument of `\multicolumn` accepts a column specifier. For `c`, `l`, and `r` the column specifier corresponds direclty to the desired alignment. However, you can alsu use others such as `p{<width of the column>}` which is justified by default.

Comment: @user193541, see added explanation to your previous question. I hope that it will help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot. very well explained!

Comment: @Zarko I still cannot figure out what is the meaning of `8em` in `\multicolumn{number of column}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{8em}|}{content}`

Comment: @user193541, from my previous comment follows that `8em` (or `8 em`) is the width of column. Width is equal of width of 8 letters M.

Comment: @Zarko Thanks. Sorry to ask: `8em` = `letter 8` an `letter M`. How about `e` meaning?

Comment: @user193541, sorry, comments are not right way to learn basic of the LaTeX. `em` is name of width of the letter `M`, as is `ex` is name of the height of the letter `x`. Please read *Not so short introduction to LaTeX 2e* (http://tug.ctan.org/info/lshort/english/lshort.pdf). There you will find basic information about (basic of)  the LaTeX.

Comment: Thanks! I wanted to post a new question but seemed it related to this question. I think I can post a new question asking about what is `em` means